# How to create a class of two integers (a sort of custom type)

Tags: java

Basically need to create a class which is custom type that has two integers: -1 and 1, instead of all the integers that exist.

If you would suggest using enum (never implemented before), could you please suggest how would that work.

```
public class PlusOrMinusOne{
    private int plusOne=1;
    private int minusOne=-1;
}
```

Comment: Not very clear, but sounds like you're looking for [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Java, but if it were me, I wouldn't make these variables private.

Comment: I have not used enum before, how could I use enum that would only have two numbers. Personally, I would like to stick to classes, as I am more comfortable using them as of now

Answer (score 1):

Java does not let you write your own primitives, and does not have operator overloading. It is therefore simply impossible to have a class such that any expressions that are of that type act like a number. In other words, given:

```java
PlusOrMinusOne a = ...;
int b = a + 1; // cannot be made to work
if (a == -1) // cannot be made to work
```

What you can do is simply create 2 instances such that they are the **only** instances of a given class. One of them is the value associated with +1, the other with -1. There is nothing specific about these 2 instances that reflects that they represent -1 or +1 - you can code them however you like.

`enum` is the general way to do this - it takes care of ensuring nobody can make instances other than the ones you defined, for example.

```
public enum PlusOrMinusOne /* horrible name, come up with a better one */ {
  PLUS_ONE(+1),
  MINUS_ONE(-1),
  ;

  private final int value;

  PlusOrMinusOne(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static PlusOrMinusOne of(int value) {
    if (value == -1) return MINUS_ONE;
    if (value == +1) return PLUS_ONE;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + value);
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public PlusOrMinusOne neg() {
    if (this == PLUS_ONE) return MINUS_ONE;
    return PLUS_ONE;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return this == PLUS_ONE ? "+1" : "-1";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using enums you can define custom fields, so in your case you can do for example:

```
 public enum CustomNumber {
        PLUS_ONE(1),
        MINUS_ONE(-1);

        public final int value;

        CustomNumber(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(CustomNumber.MINUS_ONE.value);
        System.out.println(CustomNumber.PLUS_ONE.value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
enum PlusOrMinusOne {
    PLUS_ONE(1),
    MINUS_ONE(-1);

    public final int num;

    PlusOrMinusOne(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(CustomNumber.MINUS_ONE.num);
    System.out.println(CustomNumber.PLUS_ONE.num);
}
```

Comment: How is different from my answer?